# Lucene real-time indexing?

Tags: lucene, indexing, real-time

What is the best way to achieve Lucene real-time indexing?

Comment: Real time indexing of what? Could you explain a bit more what you are looking for.

Comment: Having spent 2 years working on this off and on in solr, I have to say: solr is just not the right platform when it comes to realtime indexing.  Commits are very heavy on large indexes -- I've heard of large installs that can barely manage 1 commit per hour.  That being said, a recent project called Lucandra may prove promising -- I can't find any docs now, but I thought I heard something about no need to commit. http://github.com/tjake/Lucandra#readme

Comment: You have to explain more -- there is no specific meaning to "real-time": at minimum you need to specify what would be acceptable delay. Soft realtime (like, takes 5-10 seconds for updates to show) is not hard, for non-huge indexes, for example.

Comment: Please don't write such confusing comments (about Solr). The question is about lucene. Solr's brokenness here (closing the indexwriter on commit, not using Lucene's NRT feature) is off-topic.

Answer (score 9):

Lucene has a feature called near-real-time search to address exactly this need.

It requires that your IndexReader is in the same JVM as your IndexWriter.

You make changes with the IndexWriter, and then open a reader directly from the writer using IndexReader.open(writer), or on older Lucene releases writer.getReader().  This call will normally be very fast (in proportion to how many changes you've made since last opening a reader) as it bypasses the costly commit normally required for opening a reader.  It's able to search the un-committed changes in the writer.

This reader still searches a point-in-time snapshot from the writer, ie all changes as of when you opened it.

Answer (score 4):

Obtain an index reader from the index writer.

Update: Looks like the current method is to [open a directory reader using an index writer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#open%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter,%20boolean%29) object.

Comment: How's that going to help with real-time indexing?

Comment: By allowing searches to find documents prior to a commit point.  The reader obtained from the writer is continually updated as documents are added.

Comment: While trying to do IndexReader reader = indexWriter.getReader();
The method getReader() from the type IndexWriter is not visible.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_2/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html?is-external=true

Comment: I've just updated my answer for more recent Lucene API.

Answer (score 2):

Try Zoie

http://sna-projects.com/zoie/

Comment: Zoie has promise, however I have found the documentation and code samples severely lacking. Further with Zoie, indexing is fast if the documents to be indexed are batched up, but indexing a few documents at a time is actually extremely slow. I have personally found raw Lucene to be an easier API to use.

Answer (score 1):

The Lucene wiki has some information:
http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch

Answer (score 1):

[SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) looks promising. It is still very new, but will provide distributed Solr indexing in the [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) spirit.