# Lucene NET throwing Fatal Error: AccessViolationException

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene NET v4.8 beta, and I have a method that is calling MaybeRefresh on a SearcherManager every 5 seconds.  99.9% of the time, everything works fine.  However, 0.1% of the time, I am getting an fatal AccessViolationException error. I am not sure what is causing this fatal error.  This is the full stacktrace:

````
at System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadByte(Int64)
at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput.ReadByte()
at Lucene.Net.Store.DataInput.ReadInt32()
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos+FindSegmentsFile.Run(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexCommit)
at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Lucene.Net.Store.Directory)
at Lucene.Net.Index.StandardDirectoryReader.IsCurrent()
at Lucene.Net.Index.StandardDirectoryReader.DoOpenNoWriter(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexCommit)
at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.OpenIfChanged(Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader)
at Lucene.Net.Search.SearcherManager.RefreshIfNeeded(Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher)
at Lucene.Net.Search.ReferenceManager`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].DoMaybeRefresh()
at Lucene.Net.Search.ReferenceManager`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MaybeRefresh()
...my method that calls MaybeRefresh...```
````

Please note:

I have 2 separate services.  One service is periodically writing to the index via IndexWriter (service A), and the other is searching on the index and calling MaybeRefresh every 5 seconds (service B).  It is service B that sees this fatal error.  Service A works fine and does not have any errors.  So I believe that this has something to do with Service B, but mentioning this for full transparency in case I missed something.

If anyone can give any insight into this fatal error caused by Lucene methods, that would be appreciated!

Please also let me know of any additional details I should add to describe this error, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the error message most likely indicates you are opening the `MMapDirectory` multiple times on the same set of index files, and you are getting the exception because both instances are writing to the same memory space. I am not sure whether that can be considered a bug or not, but it should be noted that for writing, you don't need to open a RAM-intensive `MMapDirectory`, you can just use a `SimpleFSDirectory`.

```
Directory dir = new SimpleFSDirectory(filePath);
```

That being said, the following advice will make the above point moot.

### Option 1

Typically, you should limit the number of processes opening a single index to 1. If you need to write at the same time that reads happen, you can use the [near real-time search feature of Lucene](https://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-nrt-hello-world.html).

The steps involved in doing this are:

1. Open an `IndexWriter` and keep it open (register it as a singleton).
2. Create a `SearcherManager` with the `IndexWriter` as param (or alternatively, use `writer.GetReader()`).
3. Use `SearcherManager` to search.
4. Use `IndexWriter` for indexing operations.
5. `Commit()` after indexing.
6. Call `searcherManager.MaybeRefresh()` after adding a document.

As pointed out in the linked tutorial, you can use `ControlledRealTimeReopenThread` to periodically refresh the `IndexReader` in the background.

Finally, to solve the problem of opening multiple `Directory` instances (which is what is ultimately causing this issue), use a single process for both writing and reading. Since writes typically happen less often than reads, I recommend doing all of this inside of your searching service and then using a network sockets (TCP, HTTP, etc) to message the search service from the write service in order to write to/update/delete from the index.

### Option 2

If you want to open the same index in multiple processes, you can use the [Lucene.Net.Replicator](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/replicator/Lucene.Net.Replicator.html) module to write your index with one service and then publish it for replication to other services. `Lucene.Net.Replicator` is typically recommended for replicating the same index across multiple nodes in a web farm, but can also be used for writing the index in one service and reading it in another service. Essentially, for your use case you would have a separate index directory for each one of your services.

However, it will also require you to build a network service to publish the updates to. The primary difference is you wouldn't need to design a specialized web API to write/update/delete the index, instead you could use an existing API to publish your index after it is written.

References:

- [Lucene near real time search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275557/lucene-near-real-time-search)
- [Lucene real-time indexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067576/lucene-real-time-indexing)

Comment: Hi NightOwl.  Just to confirm, when you say "solve the problem of opening multiple Directory instances(which is what is ultimately causing this issue)", are you referring to  any `Directory` instance (i.e including `SimpleFSDirectory`)?  Or does this problem only occur because of opening multiple `MMapDirectory` instances specifically?

Comment: Not sure. You are the first to report the problem. Lucene has thousands of tests, but opening multiple instances of `MMapDirectory` over the same set of files is not a tested (and presumably not an expected) scenario. The tests expect that most apps will have either a singleton `IndexWriter` or a singleton `IndexReader` that handle all requests, thus only 1 directory open at a time.